# Eclipse - Why interface method consider as Open Super Implementation

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

Following an interface and an implementation class:

```
public interface MyI
     void test();
}

public MyImpl implements MyI {
     //@Override with or without @Override 
     public void test() {
     }
}
```

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking on implementation `test()` method in **Eclipse** It display a menu offering `Open Super Implementation`

[image]

When choosing `Open Super Implementation` it goes to the interface's method which **has no implementation**

Is it intentional or just an extra feature to get to interface method although naming is confusing/seems wrong?

Comment: Which eclipse version? Could you perhaps post a screenshot of that menu entry? Is it in the context menu (you are just saying, "clicking on implementation", not right-click or whatever)?

Comment: This is at least consistent with `@Override` which is given by the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @howlger It's both with or without `@Override` (updated)

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Eclipse 2018-09, When you click Ctrl+Mouse over method. added image

Comment: @user7294900 Sure, but it is not an error with `@Override` which means the method overwrites the interface method according to the [meaning of `@Override` given by the Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.4). Eclipse uses the meaning consistent with the Java language specification, even if that seems less intuitive (as it is not intuitive that `@Override` is not an error here: no super implementation is overwritten here; just an implementation of an interface method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something informative to do on the go-to-implementation (i.o. of an error). As there stands (can stand) an `@Override` that is almost regular/to be expected: the first declaration.

For **abstract methods** in an abstract super class that is likely the same.

"Implementation" hence is a bit misleading, but then there is Override.
It should be noted that the first implementation of an interface method originally could not have an `@Override`. A java change to be able to prevent errors (indeed see that the abstract method was implemented with correct signature).

Comment: Yes, `@Override` is optional for an interface, but I wanted to express that one either could remove the action go-to-implementation from UI access or let it follow up with the go-to-declaration-source.

Answer (score -1):

That's an IDE feature. As the menu entry indicates it takes you to the super method. At run-time the implementing method will be called. So it's just a feature of the IDE.

Comment: I'm asking why IDE feature called `implementation` and not for example `super`